# Symfony directory structure on cPanel site

Tags: symfony

I'm building my first Symfony site that will eventually be hosted on a shared server/cPanel site.

I'd like to have my Symfony/web content separate from the server files, though the way Symfony is structured, all the Symfony files are outside the public_html folder.  But with a cPanel setup, there's already a lot of files and folders outside the public_html folder (mail, logs, .bashrc, .cpanel, www alias... and a dozen others).

I worry that it feels messy if I put Symfony mixed in with all these files and there could be a conflict.  I would rather it be in a directory by itself.   The best idea I've had so far is to make a subdomain to host Symfony where I can manually choose the web folder, and then just do redirects to the subdomain.

What do others do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I decided to do it, and it seems like it will work pretty well.  I just use the regular cPanel public_html as the document root, upload the whole Symfony contents to that directory, but then add an .htaccess file with the contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

And that protects the main Symfony contents from public access while at the same time putting it all in a directory by itself.  It seems to work so far.  If anyone has a better idea, I'm open to it!

Comment: You could also install it into a directory that's a peer of `public_html`, maybe `/home/youruser/yourproject`, then redirect your server to use `/home/youruser/yourproject/web` instead of `/home/youruser/public_html`.

Comment: I asked the web hosting company and they said they couldn't change public_html because it was a required set-up for cPanel or something like that.