# Why would the Symfony dev mode require a 3-character subdirectory?

Tags: symfony

I'm still really new to Symfony and dealing with plenty of frustrations getting it working.  Here's my current situation.

```
http://localhost/
```

...works fine

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php
```

...works fine

```
http://localhost/bowling/
```

...A bundle I set up with a prefix "/bowling" in routing.yml.  Also works fine.  Though as I develop, I occasionally get errors.  It would be nice to run that in dev mode.  So with it working in production, I go to to

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/bowling/
```

And I get the error

```
No route found for "GET ling/"
```

After toying around with it, I found that if I add any three characters and a slash before the route URL it works.  So to get the /bowling/ URL to work in dev mode, I have to go to a URL like

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/xxx/bowling/
```

Same is true for all inner URLs.  This is a near-fresh install of Symfony 2.8 and I really haven't touched that many files yet... I've just been following tutorials and such.  This isn't how dev mode is supposed to work, is it?

**--- EDIT ---**

After a day of going through Symfony code line-by-line, I figured out that it's related to [this issue brought up in 2013](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7329) not being completely fixed when combined with [my "solution" for directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167540/symfony-directory-structure-on-cpanel-site/34168618#34168618) on a cPanel server.  Long story short...

```
$request->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME')
```

is returning "/web/app_dev.php" when it should be returning just "app_dev.php" (and so it trims the first 15 characters from the URL instead of the first 11).  I can edit the Request.php file myself but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it.  There are a dozen places where I can make a change and fix the error, I'm thinking to change

```
$baseUrl = $this->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME');
```

to

```
$baseUrl = $filename;
```

at line 1733 of Request.php (Symfony 2.8).  It fixes the error in all situations I see myself using.  Though I don't think it will work if someone decides to put their front controller in a directory other than the top level of the URL.  I would honestly love a solution where I could somehow fix this in my own bundle without editing Symfony code.  Suggestions?

Comment: possibily some strange rewrite rule of the web server?

Answer (score 0):

See this similar question:

[symfony 2 No route found for “GET /”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302270/symfony-2-no-route-found-for-get?rq=1)

Also if that doesn't work, maybe put your `routing.yml` and `routing_dev.yml` code in the question so we can see more about the problem :)

Comment: Didn't help.  I just included my routing files.

Comment: I think I did... but just in case, I tried again... still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you also add the config.yml file (condig_dev.yml) if available?

Comment: @anegrea I just put all of the config files in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/j17NXLJk).

Comment: I am worried about the framework option... Even if you are defining different children I am worried that somehow something goes wrong and they are overwritten if declared twice.